# How are MongoDB connections counted?

Tags: mongodb

When I count current connections to my MongoDB database, I receive an unexpectedly high number:

> MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.serverStatus().connections
>
> { "current" : 2044, "available" : 49156, "totalCreated" : 567801428 }

How can I retrieve more information about each of these connections, for instance, the source IP and what it is being used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get the information I needed this way:

```
netstat -vatn | grep 27017 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d ':' -f 1 | sort | uniq
```

1. Retrieve all open Mongo connections with `netstat -vatn | grep 27017`
2. Sort all connections into unique clients with `awk '{print $5}' | cut -d ':' -f 1 | sort | uniq`
3. To additionally count the number of connections or clients, append `wc -l` to #1 or #2 above

Answer (score 0):

```
$ lsof -n -i4TCP:27017  // where `27017` if your mongo port
```

Would be one way to list the connections via the OS.

As far as how they are counted there are few factors in play. One is [connection pooling](https://blog.mlab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/):

> Most MongoDB drivers support a parameter that sets the max number of
>   connections (pool size) available to your application. The connection
>   pool size can be thought of as the max number of concurrent requests
>   that your driver can service. The default pool size varies from driver
>   to driver, e.g. for Node it is 5, whereas for Python it is 100.

[MongoDB default connection pool size](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#connection-pool-configuration) is `5` as stated above in node so for each app connecting using pools you would get 5 open connections etc. See if you are using connection pools and if so if that number is higher. You could also limit the number of connection in the pool with [**`maxPoolSize`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-pool-options).

Comment: How would I find the source IP for these connections, e.g. from `lsof`?

Comment: Also, how would I determine the number of active connections coming from a connection pool?

Comment: `lsof` would give you the `USER/PID/DEVICE` and most importantly `NAME` which should be the `IP`. Not sure there is an easy way to find out `active` vs `not active` since you are dealing with connection pool.

Comment: @Kyle please elaborate what you mean by "active connections". It's not a standard term. You can get details of currently running queries with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/ . You should expect quite high number of current connections in a sharded cluster since it includes connections from replica set members, config servers, and  cross-shard connections during migration.